# Need more information on how rails model inheritance works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails app, where I have a Model called “Fruits” which contains an underlying database,
 I this DB I have columns like “Type”, “Value” and few other columns, under Type column I have data like “Apple”, “Orange”, and “Mango”.
I have other models like “Apple”, “Orange”, “Mango” all of which do not have an underlying DB but inherits from the model “Fruits” (the one which I mentioned earlier).
In my code when I write Apple.find_by_Value(some value) , how does this returns data related only to Apple ?

Comment: Because rails will know that `Apple` maps to a `type` of `Apple` in the database and will scope the query to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at a Single Table Inheritance (STI). It allows you to use several models for the same table, using the `type` column to store the name of the model for each record.

Related documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html